# ASP.NET MVC 4 How to manage userid and user content inside controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, httpcontext, user-management, simplemembership

To learn the ASP.NET MVC 4 patter I'm developing and application that has to manage some data and user content.

This is the database:

```
public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
public DbSet<Fund> Funds { get; set; }
public DbSet<Source> Sources { get; set; }
public DbSet<Portfolio> Portfolios { get; set; }
public DbSet<Quote> Quotes { get; set; }
public DbSet<Deposit> Deposits { get; set; }
```

Where relationship cardinalities are:

- UserProfile (a user) - Portfolio: 1-N
- UserProfile - Deposit: 1-N
- Portfolio - Fund: N-M
- Fund - Source: 1-N
- Fund - Quote: 1-N
- Fund - Deposit: 1-N

On the database there are also the ASP.NET Simple Membership tables: webpages_Membership, webpages_OAuthMembership, webpages_Roles, webpages_UsersInRoles.

**UserProfile Model**:

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

**Portfolio Model**:

```
public class Portfolio
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Label")]
    [MaxLength(30)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Insert a label.")]
    public string Label { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Created on")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    public virtual int UserId { get; set; } // Foreign key for UserProfile table

    public virtual ICollection<Fund> Funds { get; set; } // Linked Funds
}
```

Said that, this is what the application should make the user do:

- register/login;
- see/modify/create only is own portfolios/deposits;
- manage funds and portfolios;
- and for now this is almost all...

I post here my actual implementation of the **Index action** of Portfolio Controller. *I need the Username to get the UserId that is the foreign key on the Portfolio table*, to get only the specific user's portfolios. Then I use LINQ to make the query.

```
[Authorize]
public class PortfolioController : Controller
{
    private readonly MyDb _db = new MyDb();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string userName = null;

        if (HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            userName = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
        }

        var result = _db.UserProfiles
                        .Where(u => u.UserName.Equals(userName))
                        .Join(_db.Portfolios, u => u.UserId, p => p.UserId, (u, p) => p);

        return View(result);
    }
}
```

So, what about this approach? I already know that probably it's not the best solution...

Then, in the **Create action** *I need the UserId to associate the new portfolio with the correct user*, so what have I to do?

```
//
// GET: /Portfolio/Create

public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}

//
// POST: /Portfolio/Create

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Portfolio portfolio)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // TODO:
        // Here I need the UserId to associate the new portfolio with the user!
        // I don't want to make another LINQ query to get the UserId from Username.
        // ...

        _db.Portfolios.Add(portfolio);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(portfolio);
}
```

Of course, I need to make the same thing with the Deposit model, as the user create a new deposit and has to see/edit only his own deposits.

**What I want to know is:**

Which is the best pattern (most correct/elegant) to manage the user content and the needs of Username/UserId on many controller actions and views?

Comment: ***Best is to use:    `WebSecurity.CurrentUserId`***

Sorry I've edit the post instead of adding a comment now I'm unable to revert my edit

Comment: Thank you! I can also get directly the Username by using `WebSecurity.CurrentUserName`.